# Facebook Audience Network Ads into Adobe Air Application

Tags: flash, air, admob, ads, facebook-audience-network

We want to put facebook audience network ads & Admob together into our adobe air application. Facebook provides an official plugin for unity, but not for adobe air.

Has anyone managed to integrate facebook ads in their AIR app?

Answer (score 0):

FPAudienceNetwork ANE library:

- http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/audience-network/?lang=en
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN9KK-9f2lM&list=PLw76-mHQ5mhfncTAD4SmUyrw7CsFsikSS&index=1